# Drop rows and reset_index in a dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I was wondering why `reset_index()` has no effect in the following piece of code.

```
data = [0,10,20,30,40,50]
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=['Numbers'])
df.drop(df.index[2:4], inplace=True)
df.reset_index()
df

   Numbers
0        0
1       10
4       40
5       50
```

UPDATE:

If I use `df.reset_index(inplace=True)`, I see a new column which is not desired.

```
   index  Numbers
0      0        0
1      1       10
2      4       40
3      5       50
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because `reset_index()` has `inplace=False` as default, so you need to do `reset_index(inplace=True)`. [Docs](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.reset_index.html)

Comment: You then have to add `drop` as well: `.reset_index(inplace=True, drop=True)`

Answer (score 0):

Please try this code

```
import pandas as pd

# create a sample DataFrame
df = pd.DataFrame({'column_name': [1, 2, 0, 4, 0, 6]})

# drop rows where column 'column_name' has value of 0
df = df[df['column_name'] != 0]

# reset the index of the resulting DataFrame
df = df.reset_index(drop=True)

print(df)
```